# How to put a variable from one page to another in a tabhost?

Tags: android

In fact I'm working on an android project I have a list of events, when I click on an event I can pass the name of the event and its image but I can not put the description in a tabhost how can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'list of events'? listview?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** 
You can try using setTag method on each row which stores your description.

```
setTag(Object tag)
```

Sets the tag associated with this view.

**Option 2:**

I have similar situation in my project. This is how I achieved

1. When I created the list, I have created array of string object. I keep this as a global object in MYProjectApplication.java file. So it is available everywhere.
2. When the list is clicked I get the position and refer the corresponding description from the global string array.